# Pressing local notification, scheduled after app was closed and opened from notification, doesn't work

Tags: android, flutter, android-notifications

I have a flutter app which uses flutter_local_notifications and allows the user to schedule notifications and then pressing on notification reach onDidReceiveNotificationResponse or onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse which redirect to play a recording.

This works well, beside specific situation:

1. Schedule a notification from the app and then close it
2. Click on the notification - the app opens and plays the recording OK.
3. Schedule a notification from the app (keep it open)
4. Click on the notification - nothing happens.

I've added logs to the functions onDidReceiveNotificationResponse and onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse but didn't see anything in the log, so I understand that it didn't reach these functions.

I'm using Android Emulator Pixel 4

NotificationService:

```
class NotificationService{
  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin notificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin notificationsPluginTextOnly = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
  late DateTimeHandler dateTimeHandler;
  static final loggingService = LoggingService();
  static const classLog = "NotificationService";

  NotificationService(){
    dateTimeHandler = DateTimeHandler();
  }
  
  Future initNotification() async {
    requestPermission();
    final fcmToken = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
    loggingService.logger.i("$classLog | fcmToken: $fcmToken");
    tz.initializeTimeZones(); // Initialize timezones
    const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid = 
    AndroidInitializationSettings('flutter_logo');
    const InitializationSettings initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
      android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
      iOS: null, // Set it to null if not using iOS
    );

    notificationsPlugin.initialize(
      initializationSettings, onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: onDidReceiveNotification, 
    onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse: onDidReceiveBackgroundNotification
    );

  }

  static void onDidReceiveNotification(NotificationResponse? notificationResponse) async {
    try {
      loggingService.logger.v("$classLog | onDidReceiveNotification");
      final String categoryName = await Category.getCurrentCategoryName();
      final String recordingName = await Recording.getCurrentRecordingName(categoryName);
      
      final notificationAppLaunchDetails = await getNotificationAppLaunchDetails();
      if (notificationAppLaunchDetails?.didNotificationLaunchApp ?? false) {
        loggingService.logger.i("$classLog | The app was opened from a notification on foreground");
        runApp(MyApp(
          categoryName: categoryName,
          recordingName: recordingName,
        ));
      } else {
        loggingService.logger.i("$classLog | The app is already running, handle the notification 
        navigation");
        MyApp.navigatorKey.currentState?.push(
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => RecordingScreen(
              categoryName: categoryName,
              recordingFileName: recordingName,
              fromNotification: true,
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
      MyApp.navigatorKey.currentState?.popAndPushNamed('/initial');
    } catch (e) {
        loggingService.logger.e("$classLog | Exception occurred while open notification: $e");
        const SplashScreen();
    }
  }


  static void onDidReceiveBackgroundNotification(NotificationResponse? notificationResponse) async {
    try {
      loggingService.logger.v("$classLog | onDidReceiveBackgroundNotification");
      final String categoryName = await Category.getCurrentCategoryName();
      final String recordingName = await Recording.getCurrentRecordingName(categoryName);
      
      final notificationAppLaunchDetails = await getNotificationAppLaunchDetails();
      if (notificationAppLaunchDetails?.didNotificationLaunchApp ?? false) {
        loggingService.logger.i("$classLog | The app was opened from a notification from background");
        runApp(MyApp(
          categoryName: categoryName,
          recordingName: recordingName,
        ));
      } else {
        loggingService.logger.i("$classLog | The app is already running, handle the notification   
         navigation");
        MyApp.navigatorKey.currentState?.push(
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => RecordingScreen(
              categoryName: categoryName,
              recordingFileName: recordingName,
              fromNotification: true,
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
      MyApp.navigatorKey.currentState?.popAndPushNamed('/initial');
    } catch (e) {
        loggingService.logger.e("$classLog | Exception occurred while open notification: $e");
        const SplashScreen();
    }
  }
```

Main:

```
void main() async { 
  final int currentDayIndex = DateTime.now().weekday;  
  const classLog = "Main";
  if(currentDayIndex == 6){ // Saturday
    return;
  }
  
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,);
  await dotenv.load(fileName: "keys.env");
  var webRecaptchaSiteKey = dotenv.env['WEB_RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY'];

  await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate(
    webRecaptchaSiteKey: webRecaptchaSiteKey,
    // Default provider for Android is the Play Integrity provider. You can use the "AndroidProvider" enum to choose
    // your preferred provider. Choose from:
    // 1. debug provider
    // 2. safety net provider
    // 3. play integrity provider
    androidProvider: AndroidProvider.debug,
  );

  final FirebaseAnalytics analytics = FirebaseAnalytics.instance;
  analytics.setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true);
  
  final loggingService = LoggingService();
  loggingService.setupCyclicLogFile();

  loggingService.logger.i("$classLog | App started ${DateTime.now()}");
  final Storage storage = FirebaseStorageT();
  await storage.initialize();
  initializeTimezone();
  final String timeZoneName = await FlutterNativeTimezone.getLocalTimezone();
  tz.setLocalLocation(tz.getLocation(timeZoneName));
  
  
  await storage.signInAnonymously();
  loggingService.logger.i("$classLog | After sign-in");

  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin notificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
  final notificationAppLaunchDetails = await notificationsPlugin.getNotificationAppLaunchDetails();
  
  final observer = AppLifecycleObserver();
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(observer);
  
  if (notificationAppLaunchDetails?.didNotificationLaunchApp ?? false) {
    loggingService.logger.i("$classLog | The app was opened from a notification");
    
    try{
      final String categoryName = await Category.getCurrentCategoryName();
      final String recordingName = await Recording.getCurrentRecordingName(categoryName);

      runApp(MaterialApp(
        home: RecordingScreen(
          categoryName: categoryName,
          recordingFileName: recordingName,
          fromNotification: true,
        ),
      ));
    }
    catch(e){
      loggingService.logger.e("$classLog | failed to navigate to RecordingScreen, navigating to home screen. $e");
      runApp(
        const MyApp(),
      );
    }

  } else {
    loggingService.logger.i("$classLog | The app was launched regular");
    runApp(
      const MyApp(),
    );
  }
} 


class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key, this.categoryName, this.recordingName}) : super(key: key);
  final String? categoryName;
  final String? recordingName;
  static final navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
  static final GlobalKey<RecordingScreenState> recordingScreenKey = GlobalKey<RecordingScreenState>();

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  String? categoryName;
  String? recordingName;
  final loggingService = LoggingService();
  static const classLog = "_MyAppState";
  late NotificationService _notificationService;
  static FirebaseAnalytics analytics = FirebaseAnalytics.instance;
  static FirebaseAnalyticsObserver observer =
    FirebaseAnalyticsObserver(analytics: analytics);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
    _notificationService = NotificationService();
    _notificationService.initNotification();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
      _handleNotificationLaunch();
    }
  }

  void _handleNotificationLaunch() async {
    final notificationAppLaunchDetails = await NotificationService.getNotificationAppLaunchDetails();
    if (notificationAppLaunchDetails?.didNotificationLaunchApp ?? false) {
      try{
        final String categoryName = await Category.getCurrentCategoryName();
        final String recordingName = await Recording.getCurrentRecordingName(categoryName);
        _updateData(categoryName, recordingName);
      }
      catch(e){
        loggingService.logger.e("$classLog | failed to handle notification launch, navigating to home screen. $e");
      }
    }
  }

  void _updateData(String categoryName, String recordingName) {
    setState(() {
      this.categoryName = categoryName;
      this.recordingName = recordingName;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      navigatorObservers: <NavigatorObserver>[observer],
      navigatorKey: MyApp.navigatorKey,
      title: 'Dikduk4Shatz',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      initialRoute: '/initial',
      routes: {
        '/initial': (context) => _handleInitialRoute(context),
      },
      onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
        if ((categoryName != null || recordingName != null) &&
            settings.name == RecordingScreen.routeName) {
          return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => RecordingScreen(
              categoryName: categoryName!,
              key: MyApp.recordingScreenKey,
              recordingFileName: recordingName!,
              fromNotification: true,
            ),
          );
        }
        return null;
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _handleInitialRoute(BuildContext context) {
    if (categoryName != null && recordingName != null) {
      return RecordingScreen(
        categoryName: categoryName!,
        key: MyApp.recordingScreenKey,
        recordingFileName: recordingName!,
        fromNotification: true,
      );
    } else {
      return const SplashScreen();
    }
  }
}

class AppLifecycleObserver extends WidgetsBindingObserver {
  final loggingService = LoggingService();
  static const classLog = "AppLifecycleObserver";
  
  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.paused) {
      loggingService.logger.i("$classLog | App was closed.");
    }
  }
}
```

This works well when the app is started for the first time and also when it opens by clicking the notification, after it was closed.

I expected that after the app was opened from notification (after it was closed) that clicking on a new scheduled notification will reach the onDidReceiveNotification function (because the app is now open) and then redirected to the recording part, but according to the logs it didn't reach this function.